# High performing dataframe join in Python

Tags: python, optimization, large-data, data-processing

I have two data frames one have start Data and End Date, second data is having Just date. Basically One frame is having group and other have child data. So I want to join all the date which comes between start date and End date. Below is the code I am trying but understandably it takes quite a long time as I have large data.

```
def is_between_dates(date, start, end):
    return start <= date <= end

result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in alarm_data.iterrows():
    mask = event_data['Date'].apply(lambda x: is_between_dates(x, row['AlarmStart'], row['AlarmEnd']))
    temp_df2 = event_data[mask].copy()
    temp_df2['AlarmStart'] = row['AlarmStart']
    temp_df2['AlarmEnd'] = row['AlarmEnd']
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, temp_df2])
```

I have like 2 million data in event data frame and 200000 data in alarm data which is expected. I don't want to use spark to achieve this as it will create infrastructure burden.

Some direction will be helpful

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @possum: I asked for direction, I am not expecting anyone to solve it for me. I guess that is why we have this forum to improve our knowledge.

Comment: Try using Polars. It should be able to use multiple threads when it is possible. However, note that for large data, this will certainly be memory-bound (if not even IO-bound regarding how you load/store data or manage your RAM). Memory-bound codes often poorly scale. To solve this issue assuming it happens, the only way is not to save the huge amount of data in RAM but directly generate and compute it on the fly.

Comment: @Pijush You're asking an ambiguous question for "direction".  Read the rules, guidelines, and understand the purpose of this site here first.  Just because "improve our knowledge" is a goal doesn't mean anything goes.

Answer (score 1):

### A solution

You're doing quite heavy operations in each row so no wonder it takes time.

If you have understood your question correctly, here's one solution that's a third faster or so.

```
alarm_data["events"] = alarm_data.apply(lambda row: event_data[(row['AlarmStart'] <= event_data['Date']) & (event_data['Date'] <= row['AlarmEnd'])].index.to_list(), axis=1)

result_df = alarm_data.explode("events").join(event_data, on="events")
```

### Explanation

I used this as a sample data:

```
alarm_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "AlarmStart": [1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 1],
        "AlarmEnd": [3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 3, 2]
    }
)

event_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "Event": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
    }
)
```

This solution applies the filter directly on each row of alarm_data without a for loop. Getting rid of the second apply for event_data also helps.

This apply `alarm_data.apply(lambda row:...` will get for each row in the `alarm_data` the corresponding event indices from `event_data` as a list. The step will look about like this:

```
   AlarmStart  AlarmEnd     events
0           1         3  [0, 1, 2]
1           3         4     [2, 3]
2           5         6     [4, 5]
...
```

Next we need to explode the events to new rows with `.explode()`:

```
   AlarmStart  AlarmEnd events
0           1         3      0
0           1         3      1
0           1         3      2
1           3         4      2
...
```

And finally join rest of the event_data to the dataframe using the `events` column as the join key:

`.join(event_data, on="events")`

The result will look about like this:

```
   AlarmStart  AlarmEnd events  Date Event
0           1         3      0     1     A
0           1         3      1     2     B
0           1         3      2     3     C
1           3         4      2     3     C
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Original answer

Your question needs to be rephrased as it is not obvious what you want to achieve without reading it multiple times inspecting the code. Nevertheless, if I understood correctly, you have a large `event_data` with `Date`, and you want to add information about the corresponding `AlarmStart` and `AlarmEnd` from `alarm_data`.

The main performance issue in your code is the `pandas.concat`, which creates a new dataframe every time, 200000 times in your case.  This is clearly inefficient, since a large amount of memory is being copied a number of times. Moreover, `dataframe.iterrows()` is also really slow for any large dataframe, and is heavily discouraged (read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/5242412)).

What I would suggest instead is to make a copy of `event_data` (preferably with dummy columns for `AlarmStart` and `AlarmEnd`) and modify it in place. I assume there is no overlap between the different intervals between `AlarmStart` and `AlarmEnd`, so that you can uniquely assign these values to each `event`. Use `AlarmStart` and `AlarmEnd` from `alarm_data` with [`pandas.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) to create your list of bins which you can pass to [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) as `pandas.cut(event_data['Date'], bins, labels=False)` to categorise your events and obtain the corresponding bin number. Use these bin numbers to index `AlarmStart` and `AlarmEnd` and substitute the values in `event_data`. Note that `pandas.cut` does not accept overlapping `IntervalIndex`, so this will be the option for performance only if there is no overlap between your intervals. Also, the intervals might need to be ordered.

I hope the explanation was clear enough. Read the examples from the documentation and try playing with a subset of your data first.

---

### Example

Following comments that this does not really answer the question, I use a similar dataset as the other answer for demonstration. Note that this **WILL NOT** work if your intervals overlap (You did not specify this in the question). The other answer is more general, but I believe this is quicker if the intervals do not overlap, although I haven't tested either solutions to any large dataset.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd

In [2]: edges = np.sort(np.random.randint(1, 100, 10))

In [3]: alarm_data = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "AlarmStart": edges[:-1],
   ...:         "AlarmEnd": edges[1:],
   ...:     }
   ...: )
   ...: 
   ...: event_data = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "Date": np.random.randint(edges.min(), edges.max(), 7),
   ...:         "Event": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
   ...:     }
   ...: )

In [4]: bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(alarm_data['AlarmStart'], alarm_data['AlarmEnd'])

In [5]: alarm_data
Out[5]: 
   AlarmStart  AlarmEnd
0           1         5
1           5        13
2          13        18
3          18        21
4          21        33
5          33        46
6          46        47
7          47        76
8          76        87

In [6]: event_data
Out[6]: 
   Date Event
0    42     A
1    18     B
2    29     C
3    49     D
4    15     E
5    44     F
6    62     G

In [7]: bins
Out[7]: IntervalIndex([(1, 5], (5, 13], (13, 18], (18, 21], (21, 33], (33, 46], (46, 47], (47, 76], (76, 87]], dtype='interval[int64, right]')

In [8]: res = pd.cut(event_data['Date'], bins)

In [9]: event_data[['AlarmStart', 'AlarmEnd']] = [[x.left, x.right] for x in res]

In [10]: event_data
Out[10]: 
   Date Event  AlarmStart  AlarmEnd
0    42     A          33        46
1    18     B          13        18
2    29     C          21        33
3    49     D          47        76
4    15     E          13        18
5    44     F          33        46
6    62     G          47        76
```

Comment: If you can't answer the question because it is vague and you need clarification it should be a comment.

Comment: @possum @Ouroborus I believe I did answer the question, although it is not as general as the other answer. However, it is very likely that there is only one `Alarm` in question, so the intervals might be disjoint. I did not demonstrate it however, since I was at work, and I forgot about it later. I have now added an example to demonstrate.

Comment: try providing numbers, X perforemd in 1 sec, and Y performed in 0.2 sec. performance refactoring should be matched by figures and its impact.